# Intent shows class not found error in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

i have an app in two different sources **Android studio and Eclipse**. Then i have a **Lib** for my app its developed by Android Studio, Once i convert my Lib project into JAR file and import into the eclipse IDE. Everything will working fine but one of the Intent is not working.Its shows run time error class not found error.

I can add the **jar** in Lib folder and make it as build path, I unable to find the solution. below the ways i can try to fix the error but no more success.

the FullscreenActivity.class is not found error is shown. **Its working in Android studio but not working in Eclipse IDE.**

Way 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(adViewContext, FullscreenActivity.class);
```

Way 2:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClass(adViewContext,FullscreenActivity.class);
```

Way 3:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName(adViewContext, "com.pckname.name.FullscreenActivity");
```

Way 4:

```
try {
            intent.setClass(adViewContext, Class.forName("com.pckname.name.FullscreenActivity"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Way 5:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        Class<?> activityClass = null;
        try {
            //activityClass = Class.forName("com.pckname.name." + FullscreenActivity.class);
            activityClass = Class.forName("com.pckname.name.FullscreenActivity");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert activityClass != null;
        intent.setClass(adViewContext, activityClass);
```

Way 6:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(adViewContext, FullscreenActivity.class);
        intent.setComponent(componentName);
```

**I have tried this codes for calling the another activity from App to JAR class but error is occurs.**

**when i use Way 5 method i got below error,**

```
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892): Process: com.example.sampleappwithaar, PID: 14892
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:78)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.content.Intent.setClass(Intent.java:6855)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at com.adserversdk.dj.sdk_interstitial_banner_ads.adserver.InterstitialBannerAds_AdView$MyWebViewClient.onPageFinished(InterstitialBannerAds_AdView.java:527)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:224)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:72)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
04-16 12:04:55.347: E/AndroidRuntime(14892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**when i use Way 1 method i got below error,**

```
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507): Process: com.example.sampleappwithaar, PID: 16507
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/path/path/FullscreenActivity;
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at com.adserversdk.dj.sdk_interstitial_banner_ads.adserver.InterstitialBannerAds_AdView$MyWebViewClient.onPageFinished(InterstitialBannerAds_AdView.java:504)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:224)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:72)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pckname.name..FullscreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sampleappwithaar-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    ... 10 more
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adserversdk.dj.sdk_interstitial_banner_ads.adserver.FullscreenActivity
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:230)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:223)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        ... 12 more
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pckname.name..FullscreenActivity
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):        ... 11 more
04-16 12:15:14.917: E/AndroidRuntime(16507):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: can you share the error

Comment: show full exception stacktrace

Comment: Define the activity in your manifest file

Comment: Yes . . i can define in my manifest file

Comment: @PhanVanLinh i update my question with error list

Comment: check you add this activity tag in manifest file or not , this error occur when activity tag is missing from manifest file

Comment: @unzila no i added in manifest file

Comment: this activity is in your lib jar file or u made this activity?

Comment: the activity class  inside my lib jar also the class extends AppCompatActivity  @unzila

Comment: then you check your jar file is embedded in your project correctly or not check this link for importing jar in your project https://www.edureka.co/community/4028/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse

Comment: other class files executed correctly, except this one @unzila

Comment: you check your activity class in jar file is public or not

Comment: its a public one

Comment: ref ink : - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html